# How to handle possible duplicate in first posts review section

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

I've seen a lot of questions recently in the first posts review section which could possibly be duplicates. I was wondering how to review posts such as this. The two options I had were the following:

1. Search for a duplicate question and flag it as such.
2. Mark it as "No Action Needed" if it is a good question, despite there possibly being a duplicate somewhere on the site.

Is it my duty as a first posts reviewer to check for duplicates, or is this supposed to be left for triage questions? If I check for duplicates for every single first post that I review, the review time will increase significantly. If everyone does this, it will take a lot longer for posts to be reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of first/last posts is to address *all* of the problems that you can with that post.  A post being a duplicate would qualify as a problem.